# PHP PDO (MSSQL) inserts control characters around offset 0x0235

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo

I'm using PDO (php5-sybase) (say) like so:

> $stmt = $pdoMSSQL->prepare("INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES :val");
> $stmt->bindValue(":val",'whatever');
>
> $stmt->execute();

Assume the actual SQL is much longer (and this happens with ANY SQL, not just INSERT)

When looking at a packet capture (of a NON fragmented packet, < 1000 data bytes) containing the SQL whilst enroute to TCP 1433 of the MSSQL server there is invariably a set of ?control? characters like \x01 \x01 \x00 \xa8 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 at offset 0x235, in the middle of the query text.

If the query isn't big enough to reach 0x235 then the original text is verbatim per the prepare and bind statements, no wierd string.

Does any one know if this is controlled by a setting somewhere?  (I only have php clients that I can packet capture from, I've confirmed the above on more than one environment)

Dave

Comment: Out of curiosity: is this a problem? Like, did you discover it while debugging a specific MySQL issue, or did you just happen to come across it while looking at network traffic?

Comment: Hmmm, lets say it's an incongruity.  I don't like incongruity.  If there is a good reason, then obviously no issue, but if not or if there is a way to "opt out" I'd prefer to not have them.

Comment: That works for me. I also just realized I mentioned "MySQL" in my comment, which now bothers me since you clearly refer to MSSQL. I can't leave that hanging out there.  :)

Comment: yes, the observed behaviour is definitely MSSQL (2008r2)